# Svelte transition between pages (exitBeforeEnter)

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, framer-motion

Im trying to transition between SvelteKit pages but the transition
of next page should start after actual `out:` transition finishes.

In framer motion react there is a prop called `exitBeforeEnter`, is anything similar in svelteKit or maybe lib `svelte-motion`?

```
// Home page.
<main in:fly={{ y: 100, duration: 300 }} out:fly={{ y: -100, duration: 100 }}>
    <slot />
</main>

// About page.
<main in:fly={{ y: 100, duration: 300 }} out:fly={{ y: -100, duration: 100 }}>
    <slot />
</main>
```

Comment: I think there are only workarounds like https://www.sveltelab.dev/0hdeed8t56im9e0 or https://www.sveltelab.dev/0qqj5589kjdjfs6

Comment: @Corrl They both seem to work pretty well, thanks for sharing.
The second one is more programatic which i can customize it even more than rely on a fixed delay